# How to fix error in gradle android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

An error occurs during build:

**Gradle sync failed: Could not get unknown property 'build' for root project 'Svetofor' of type org.gradle.api.Project.**

**Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'build' for root project 'Svetofor' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.getMissingProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:85)
at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript$ScriptDynamicObject.getMissingProperty(BasicScript.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.getProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:62)
at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.getProperty(BasicScript.java:66)
at build_cn9w26wxe6fc7p57z1l3a9w12.run(C:\Users\acosm\AndroidStudioProjects\Svetofor\build.gradle:1)
at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
... 164 more**

build.gradle (Svetofor) :

```
 build.gradle(Project: AndroidStudioProjects)
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

    }




// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.


    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Remove first line. you dont need this `build.gradle(Project: AndroidStudioProjects)`